# Change colors displayed on legend - Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, legend

In order to fit with a global colororder scheme, I need to change the color of my surface plot
after I have created it.  I have struggled to update the legend to the new color order.

I plot several surfaces and create a legend for them:
hSurf(i) = surf(hAx,...)
legend({'surface1','surface2','surface3'})

I modify the color of the surfaces successfully:
hSurf(i).CData = CDataNew;

How to update the legend to this new color order?

1. Legend does not automatically update when I change surface CData property.
2. Deleting current legend and creating a new one does not work either
3. Changing color order of axes (Ax.ColorOrder) also does not work, also not in any combination with the two items above.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. You're asking something about graphics, a picture or two to help show what you've got vs what you want would be helpful too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.